# Post-increment and variable re-use in a single statement, Perl 5 vs Perl 6

Tags: perl, undefined-behavior, raku, sequence-points

A line of code that I naively thought would translate fairly literally between Perl 6 and Perl 5 in fact did not, due to differences in how a post-increment variable is being handled.

This Perl 6 yields the desired result, a magic square: [[8, 1, 6], [3, 5, 7], [4, 9, 2]]

```
my @sq; my $n = 3; my $i = 1; my $x = $n/2; my $y = 0;
@sq[($i%$n ?? $y-- !! $y++) % $n][($i%$n ?? $x++ !! $x) % $n] = $i++ for 0..$n**2 - 1;
say join ' ', $_ for @sq;
```

The 'same' code in Perl 5 does not: [[8, 1, 3], [9, 5, 7], [4, 6, 2]]

```
$n = 3; $i = 1; $x = $n/2; $y = 0;
$sq[($i%$n ? $y-- : $y++) % $n][($i%$n ? $x++ : $x) % $n] = $i++ for 0..$n**2 - 1;
say join ' ', @$_ for @sq;
```

Both work correctly if the statement is split up, and all the increments and decrements are done after the assignment, e.g. in Perl 5:

```
for (0 .. $n**2 - 1) {
    $sq[ $y%$n ][ $x%$n ] = $i;
    $i%$n ? $y-- : $y++;
    $x++ if $i%$n;
    $i++;
}
```

If the return value of an increment or decrement operation is value of the variable *before* the operation, then Perl 5 would be seem to be in the wrong.  But experimenting with the code showed that the result of the `$i%$n` conditions was the source of the difference, so seemingly Perl 6 may be relying upon the value of `$i` in a way that is not strictly guaranteed.

Thus I should have been more surprised that Perl 6 worked, than that Perl 5 didn't?

Comment: *"the return value of an increment or decrement operation is value of the variable before the operation*" Yes, but the value of `$i` is used on both sides of the equal sign, so the result that is put into the array may be the value before the operation, but the value of `$i` in the indexing operation could be the value after? See also: [Perl increment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43546839/2173773)

Comment: Is this for the obfuscated Perl contest?

Comment: It's from rosettacode.org, people have been know to showboat...

Comment: @HåkonHægland you should make that an answer.  the only problem here is that perl5 evaluates the right side of a scalar assignment first, while perl6 seems to do the left.

Answer (score 9):

Both Perl 5 and Perl 6 do not promise defined behavior if you modify and read the same variable within a single statement.

The Perl 6 synopses talk about [sequence points in the context of parallel execution](https://github.com/perl6/specs/blob/master/S03-operators.pod#Sequence-points), but I believe they also apply to the read+write problem within statements.

But in general, you simply cannot rely on this in either language.

Comment: Could static analysis of code spot the potential for undefined behavior due to this? (Where "this" is the combination of multiple uses of a variable in a single statement where one of the uses is either an explicit modification of it or a method call -- because a method call might modify a value.)

Comment: @raiph, Obviously, it could catch some cases. There might even be a `perlcritic` rule that does just that. But it couldn't catch all cases either. For example, there's no way to know if `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` will be aliased to the same var or not in `sub { ++$_[0] + --$_[1] }`. That's why it's undefined behaviour rather than a compile-time error.

Comment: Re "*Both Perl 5 and Perl 6 do not promise defined behavior if you modify and read the same variable within a single statement.*", Not quite. Perl5 actually does more or less document that the RHS of an assignment will be evaluated before the LHS. e.g. `local $x = f($x);` and `my $x = f($x);` are valid. It's a grey area because while specific cases are documented as valid, it's not clear to what extent this is true. But there is a basis in the documentation, and all versions and builds of Perl5 consistently execute the RHS of assignments separately and before their LHS.

Comment: In short, you *can* rely on Perl5's behaviour here. (You shouldn't though; it's hard to read.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the difference between the Perl 5 and Perl 6 codes is that the Perl 5 code uses the updated `$i` earlier than Perl 6. For example, the following Perl 5 code:

```
my $n = 3;
my $i = 2;
my $x = 5/2;
my $y = -1;
my @sq;
$sq[ ($i % $n ? $y-- : $y++) % $n] [ ($i % $n ? $x++ : $x) % $n ] = $i++;
say "x = $x, y = $y";
```

prints:

```
x = 2.5, y = 0
```

whereas the same Perl 6 code:

```
my $n = 3;
my $i = 2;
my $x = 5/2;
my $y = -1;
my @a;
@sq[ ($i % $n ?? $y-- !! $y++) % $n][ ($i % $n ?? $x++ !! $x) % $n ] = $i++;
say "x = $x, y = $y";
```

prints

```
x = 3.5, y = -2
```

so the Perl 5 code uses the updated value of `$i++` on the right hand side (i.e. `$i = 3` to compute `$i % $n` on the left hand side, whereas Perl 6 uses the old value `$i = 2` to compute the indices on the left hand side of the equation.